# Showing matplotlib plots from function in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a problem regarding showing pyplots in tkinkter. I have a function `plot_function` that returns 4 matplotlib.pyplot-plots. I want to be able to show these plots in a tkinter GUI, and show one plot in the beginning and display the other three with two "next" and "previous" buttons. The `plot_funtion` is only run once.

At the moment I'm trying to do the following (simplified):

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
class GUI:

def plot_function(self):
    ...
    # Generating plots #
    ...
    self.plots = [plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4]
    self.init_plots()

def init_plots(self):    # Showing the inital plot, plt1
    self.plot_ctr = 0
    fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi = 80)
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plot1.show(self.plots[0])
    first_fig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,self.frame1)
    first_fig.draw()
    first_fig.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
    self.master.update_idletasks()


def next_plot(self):

    if self.plot_ctr < 3:
        self.plot_ctr += 1
    else: 
        self.plot_ctr = 0
    self.first_fig.config(image = self.plots[self.plots_ctr])
    self.master.update_idletasks()

def prev_plot(self):
    
    if self.plot_ctr > 0:
        self.plot_ctr -= 1
    else: 
        self.plot_ctr = 3
    self.first_fig.config(image = self.plots[self.plots_ctr])
    self.master.update_idletasks()

def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master, relief = tk.RAISED, highlightbackground = "black", highlightthickness = 1)
    self.frame1.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.next_btn = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = "Next plot", width = 10,  command = self.next_plot)
    self.prev_btn = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = "Previous plot", width = 10,  command = self.prev_plot)
    self.prev_btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    self.next_btn.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 10, pady = 10)
     

root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I feel very unsure on how to properly use TkAgg and would be very grateful on any tips on how I would get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how you could organize your code to rotate a sequence of `matplotlib` figures embedded in a `tkinter` window

```
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = list(range(10))
        self.y0 = self.x[:]
        self.y1 = [5 for _ in range(10)]
        self.y2 = [-y for y in self.y0]
        self.d = [self.y0, self.y1, self.y2]

    def get_next_dataset(self):
        y = self.d.pop(0)
        self.d.append(y)
        return self.x, y


class MPLGraph(Figure):

    def __init__(self, data):
        Figure.__init__(self, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.data = data

    def obtain_next_figure(self):
        self.plot = self.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot.plot(*self.data.get_next_dataset())
        return self


class GraphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, graphs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page Example")
        self.title_label.pack()
        self.pack()
        self.next_graph_btn = tk.Button(self, text='next graph', command=self.obtain_next_figure)
        self.next_graph_btn.pack()
        self.graphs = graphs

        self.obtain_next_figure()

    def obtain_next_figure(self):
        try:  # protects against AttributeError the first time when self.figure_widget not yet exists yet
            self.figure_widget.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.add_mpl_figure(self.graphs.obtain_next_figure())

    def add_mpl_figure(self, fig):
        self.mpl_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        self.figure_widget = self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.figure_widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    graph_page = GraphPage(root, MPLGraph(Data()))

    root.mainloop()
```